# Attach a particular profile2 form to user registration form

Tags: 7, users

I have about 3 profile types each with their own registration path. But there's one without a path.  I want to attach this to the main registration form. So that it shows when adding user on the main user add page but not other pages.

i got it to show with the code below but error when saving the user.

Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to profile2_save() must be an instance of Profile, instance of ProfileType given,, called in C://....

```
function short_fixes_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $current_user_role = in_array('family',$user->roles);
  $form['account']['status']['#access'] = FALSE ;
  if($_GET['q'] == 'admin/people/create' && $current_user_role){
      $form_state['profiles'] = array(
        'family' => profile2_get_types('family')
      );
      profile2_attach_form($form, $form_state);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$user_register_form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
$form_state['profiles'] = array(
'CUSTOM_PROFILE_TYPE_NAME' => profile2_get_types('CUSTOM_PROFILE_TYPE_NAME')
);
profile2_attach_form($user_register_form, $form_state);
print(drupal_render($user_register_form));
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives a huge clue on how i eventually got it working. I'm only doing this through hook_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state). It works. Thank you.